# Youtube api campo duracion/tags no se muestran

Tags: api, youtube

Hola estoy haciendo pruebas para listar videos dado un canal.

```
$playlistItemsResponse = $youtube->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems('snippet,contentDetails', array(
    'playlistId' => $uploadsListId,
    'maxResults' => 50,

     ));
```

El contentDetails solo me indica el videoId y el videoPublishedAt.

Con esa petición no me regresa la duracion ni los tags asoaciados al video, alguna idea para que me indique esos datos?

Gracias

Comment: Muestra el resultado de esto: `var_dump($playlistItemsResponse);` para ver cómo viene la respuesta. Y muestra la forma en que intentas sacar la información de la respuesta. La duración por ejemplo viene como una propiedad a la que puedes acceder así: `$objeto->duration` donde `$objeto` representaría el objeto `contentDetails`

Comment: La solución es hacer una petición en batch (hasta 50 id videos) y me retorna la info adicional (tags y duracion), una lástima que no permita hacerlo todo en una petición.

Comment: No entiendo... me parece que el problema es que estás usando mal la API. No puede ser que para obtener info de un sólo vídeo tengas que traer 50 vídeos. Las API suelen tener métodos para diferentes cosas, quizá en lugar de usar algo como `playlistItems` puedes usar algo específico para un vídeo determinado según su id, etc.

Comment: He listado los videos de un canal y para traer los tags y duracion de los videos listados, necesito realizar otra petición con parts=contentDetails y traer los datos adicionales.

Comment: Realmente no uso la API de YouTube por lo que no podría hablarte con toda propiedad, sin embargo no asumiría como normal tener que enviar dos peticiones para obtener unos resultados. O algo estás haciendo mal o estás usando el punto de entrada equivocado para lo que quieres. ¿Ya revisaste [la documentación de la API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems?hl=es-419)? Explica lo que hace cada método, lo que devuelve y por tanto la forma en que habría que leer los resultados. A la izquierda aparecen los diferentes métodos. No estoy seguro que estés usando el adecuado.

Comment: Encontré mi pregunta en un foro de stackoverflow inglés y decian exactamente lo mismo. Hay que hacer dos peticiones para obtener los datos extras.

Comment: Este es el link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27393842/contentdetails-or-duration-not-coming-using-youtube-v3-api/27415212

Comment: Aca otro link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47277259/how-to-get-content-details-in-youtube-search-api-v3-swift?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Como dicen algunos usuarios en comentarios (1er enlace de tus comentarios), me parece algo estúpido tener que hacer eso y me extraña que, siendo Google, no haya una forma más fácil de hacerlo. Tiene que haberla, estoy casi seguro. Pero como no uso esa API no puedo hablarte con más propiedad. Mira [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36387404/5587982), allí se habla de una consulta en dos etapas, pero porque no se conoce el id del canal. [Esta otra respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20795628/5587982) puede ser también interesante. Y revisar todo ese hilo en busca de otras pistas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es hacer una petición en batch (hasta 50 id videos) para retornar  la info adicional (tags y duracion), una lástima que no permita hacerlo todo en una petición.
Aca otro hilo donde lo explica https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27393842/contentdetails-or-duration-not-coming-using-youtube-v3-api/27415212